# Got TypeError when adding return_indices=True to nn.MaxPool2d in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, typeerror, autoencoder

I am New to pyotch, i am trying to create an autoencoder in pytorch, here is my code

The encoder:

```py
# B = Batch size
# encoder (B, 3, 224, 224) => (B, 8)
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_cnn = nn.Sequential(
            # input shape: (B, 3, 224, 224) =>
            nn.Conv2d(3, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,return_indices=True)
            # shape: (B, 16, 55, 55) =>
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # shape: (B, 32, 28, 28) =>
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,return_indices=True),
            # output shape: (B, 64, 7, 7)
        )
        self.flat = nn.Flatten(start_dim=1) # shape: (B, 64*7*7)
        self.encoder_fc = nn.Sequential(
            # input shape: (B, 64*7*7)
            nn.Linear(64*7*7, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # shape: (B, 1024)
            nn.Linear(1024, 8),
            nn.Sigmoid()
            # output shape: (B, 8)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder_cnn(x)
        x = self.flat(x)
        x = self.encoder_fc(x)
        return x
```

The decoder

```py
# B = Batch size
# decoder (B, 8) => (B, 3, 224, 224)
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.decoder_fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(8, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(1024, 64*7*7),
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )
        self.unflat = nn.Unflatten(dim=1, unflattened_size=(64, 7, 7))
        self.decoder_cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxUnpool2d(2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.MaxUnpool2d(2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.decoder_fc(x)
        x = self.unflat(x)
        x = self.decoder_cnn(x)
        return x
```

When i test the encoder, i got this [error](https://pastebin.com/gukY4brz)

```
encoder = Encoder().to(device)
decoder = Decoder().to(device)
test_img = torch.unsqueeze(train_data[0], dim=0)
print(encoder(test_img))
```

thanks for any help :P

ps: i tried to remove the `return_indices=True` in `nn.MaxPool2d(2,return_indices=True)` and the encoder will runs successfully
but there will be another error when i run this:

```
encoder = Encoder().to(device)
decoder = Decoder().to(device)
test_img = torch.unsqueeze(train_data[0], dim=0)
codes = encoder(test_img)
print(decoder(codes).shape)
```

error: TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'indices'

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

[When `return_indices=True`, `nn.MaxPool2d.forward` returns a tuple `(out, indices)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool2d.html#torch.nn.MaxPool2d). You need `indices` for `nn.MaxUnpool2d` later. However, you put the first `nn.MaxPool2d` in `Encoder` inside an `nn.Sequential` before `nn.Conv2d`. This is problematic when `return_indices=True` because then the returned tuple is given as input to `nn.Conv2d`, but [`nn.Conv2d.forward` expects a tensor as its first argument](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#torch.nn.Conv2d). That's why you get the `TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments`. So you need to both keep `indices` and ensure only `out` is given to the next layer.

## Solution

The fix is to split the sequential modules using `nn.MaxPool2d` as the delimiter. You also need to do the same for `Decoder`. It looks something like below

```py
# B = Batch size
# encoder (B, 3, 224, 224) => (B, 8)
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_cnn1 = nn.Sequential(
            # input shape: (B, 3, 224, 224) =>
            nn.Conv2d(3, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        )
        self.max_pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,return_indices=True)
        self.encoder_cnn2 = nn.Sequential(
            # shape: (B, 16, 55, 55) =>
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # shape: (B, 32, 28, 28) =>
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
        )
        self.max_pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,return_indices=True)
        self.flat = nn.Flatten(start_dim=1) # shape: (B, 64*7*7)
        self.encoder_fc = nn.Sequential(
            # input shape: (B, 64*7*7)
            nn.Linear(64*7*7, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # shape: (B, 1024)
            nn.Linear(1024, 8),
            nn.Sigmoid()
            # output shape: (B, 8)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder_cnn1(x)
        x, indices1 = self.max_pool1(x)
        x = self.encoder_cnn2(x)
        x, indices2 = self.max_pool2(x)
        x = self.flat(x)
        x = self.encoder_fc(x)
        return x, indices1, indices2  # also return the indices

# B = Batch size
# decoder (B, 8) => (B, 3, 224, 224)
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.decoder_fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(8, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(1024, 64*7*7),
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )
        self.unflat = nn.Unflatten(dim=1, unflattened_size=(64, 7, 7))
        self.max_unpool1 = nn.MaxUnpool2d(2)
        self.decoder_cnn1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        )
        self.max_unpool2 = nn.MaxUnpool2d(2)
        self.decoder_cnn2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        )
    def forward(self, x, indices1, indices2):  # accept the indices
        x = self.decoder_fc(x)
        x = self.unflat(x)
        x = self.max_unpool1(x, indices2)
        x = self.decoder_cnn1(x)
        x = self.max_unpool2(x, indices1)
        x = self.decoder_cnn2(x)
        return x
```

Then you can run the encoder and the decoder like so

```py
encoder = Encoder()
decoder = Decoder()
test_img = torch.unsqueeze(torch.rand(3, 224, 224), dim=0)
codes, indices1, indices2 = encoder(test_img)
print(decoder(codes, indices1, indices2).shape)
```

## Caveat

The code above runs without encountering `TypeError`s related to wrong arguments like the ones in the question. However, it raises a different error about the shape of `indices1`. I suspect it has something to do with the kernel size or stride or padding in the max unpooling layers in the decoder, but frankly I'm not familiar enough with computer vision to debug this error. That said, the above code does solve the errors in the question, so I think this post still counts as an answer.